# Make a nested to-do-list

Tags: 7, theming

Finally I get to ask my first drupal-related question here. I'm glad to be here ;)

I'm planning to create some goal-management functionality like this:

```
Goal 1: Write a nice little module

    Sub-goal 1.1: Get information

        Check google and stackexchange

    Sub-goal 1.1 achieved

    Sub-goal 1.2 Implement the module

        Do the coding

    Sub-goal 1.2 not yet achieved 

Goal 1 not yet achieved
```

The idea here is that the user will be able to nest as many sub-goals as desired. The nested list above should be displayed on the website, and the user should be able to add additional (sub-) goals, or mark already created (sub-)goals as completed.

Is there already some module that provides this kind of functionality?

If not I will have to do the coding in good old php, but I have no idea how I can make a render-able array out of this kind of data. Creating nestable goals is easy in php (I could make them objects, for example), but making drupal display them right seems pretty hard (I guess I'll need to make a nested array and put it into theme_item_list()?). Does anyone know some good resources on that toppic?

Thanks in advance for any advice and/or useful links!

Comment: Actually i am not fully clear about what you wants to do but here is a module related to Goals https://www.drupal.org/project/goals. You can check this one.

Comment: Thank you very much @Smalution! I've seen the module before, but I believe that it doesn't help you in displaying a nested list like the above. It seems a wonderful addition for rewarding users for the completion of goals. However, rewarding users will only be part of my project later on. For now, I only want to display a nested list, where new sub-items can be added interactively.

Comment: Have you decided what you will be using as a base? Node? Entity? In any case, sounds like you need something along the lines of field_collection with inline editing. Think of a node as a Goal. Node title is your goal name, additionally you need to create Status (Goal completed/not) and Sub Goal field collection with Unlimited values. And this field collection will have title, description, status fields. So when you're editing this node, you will now be able to add unlimited sub-goals.

Comment: Thanks @Beebee! I'll try that out - will report all results as soon as I something working. (Might take a little while, very busy at the moment)

Comment: You can use nesting of taxonomy. If you prefer entityreference you can use https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view for views nesting. Also have you checked https://www.drupal.org/project/mytinytodo, it might solve to your task ?